# Education EV3 Software Site Licence - installation on teachers computers?

Tags: ev3

WE've recently purchased some mindstorms ev3 education sets plus the site licence of the Software.
in Switzerland many teachers do their preparations at home, so my question is, am I allowed to install the software on a computer at home or a notebook which is not constantly located at the school adress? It's really a Problem for us if that's not possible ...
Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can check out 
https://education.lego.com/nl-nl/educationdownloads/productpage/?AccessLink=985ff951-4b98-467d-9f16-687487a43784&ignorereferer=true

I think this is were you can find the student version, quite similar to the teachers version.